# Azure Data Factory SAP ECC OData connection parameters

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory, sap-erp, sap-gateway

I try to connect to a OData service available in an SAP ECC system with client number as parameter: https://system:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/srv_name/?sap-client=100. The url mentioned in the official documentation is without parameters: http://eccsvrname:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/zgw100_dd02l_so_srv/ and indeed the connection does not work (Integration Runtime is configured) How can I set default URL parameters in the linked service properties JSON?

Comment: does OData work in browser? you should separate OData errors from Azure configuration errors

Comment: Yes, it works fine if I specify the parameter sap-client=100. Without the sap-client parameter the connection is not authorized as the request is routed by default to another client where the user used for the connection does not exist. I would like to know how to troubleshoot further.